# Draggable/Droppable: trigger a drop on location after time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Relevant Code:

```
$( ".tile" ).draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  start:function ( event, ui){
    setTimeout(function(){
      destroyHelper();
      doSomething();
    },1000);
  },
  stop:function( event, ui ) {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

What I'm trying to do: a set amount of time since the dragging has begun, force the item being dragged to drop even if the user does not unclick. The drop code runs as intended the user is still dragging the item. I can't seem to destroy the helper, stop the dragging process from continuing, or force a drop (unclick) to be recognized

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).trigger("mouseup");
```

I have found that the above code forces a drop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".tile" ).draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  start:function ( event, ui){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $( ".tile" ).trigger("dragstop");
    },1000);
  },
  stop:function( event, ui ) {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, draggable objects css value is position:relative; It happens, if position changes to static in start it can be continued or ok or vice versa

```
  jQuery(".draggable_class_name_1").draggable({
     start:function(event,ui)
     {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:static !important;');
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
       }, 1000);
     },
     stop:function(event,ui)
     {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
     }
  });
```

or vice versa

```
  jQuery(".draggable_class_name_2").draggable({
     start:function(event,ui)
     {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:static !important;');
       }, 1000);
     },
     stop:function(event,ui)
     {
        jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
     }
  });
```

```js
      jQuery(".draggable_class_name_1").draggable({
         start:function(event,ui)
         {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:static !important;');
            var t = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
           }, 1000);
         },
         stop:function(event,ui)
         {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_1').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
         }
      });

      jQuery(".draggable_class_name_2").draggable({
         start:function(event,ui)
         {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
            var t = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:static !important;');
           }, 1000);
         },
         stop:function(event,ui)
         {
            jQuery('.draggable_class_name_2').css('cssText','position:relative !important;');
         }
      });
```

```css
.draggable_class_name_1 {
   margin-bottom:25px;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;
   border:1px solid red;
   cursor:move;
}
.draggable_class_name_2 {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;
   border:1px solid red;
   cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable_class_name_1"><div>Drag 1</div></div>
<div class="draggable_class_name_2"><div>Drag 2</div></div>
```